# Issue with # in url when passing Form Builder parameter

Tags: formbuilder, caldera-forms

We are looking to create a page with a form builder view that shows existing data from a  searchkit view. We would also like to add a Caldera form that allows the user to submit additional data. We want to send our notices that include a link with a checksum and contact id to populate the page. Each element works correctly on its own. The issue is when we put them on the same page as each wants a different format. Here are examples:

The following works fine for the Form Builder piece but not Caldera.

`https://example.com/form/#/?cid=<<contact_id>>&checksum=<<checksum>>`

This works fine for the Caldera piece but not Form Builder.

`https://example.com/form/?cid=<<contact_id>>&checksum=<<checksum>>`

The issue is the "#/" I am not sure there is a way for this to work. Throwing it out there to see if anyone has an idea before I look for other approaches. Thanks